# Modelling XACML policy for dynamic role and attribute

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac

I want to write an [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa)/[xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml) policy which will verify whether the user role and attribute match with the role and attribute for a particular activity.

The user role and attributes as well as activity role and attributes should be passed as input to the XACML policy for evaluation. The response should be `PERMIT` if the user role and attribute match with the activity role and attributes.

e.g. :

- Activity : View Trades in USD on NYSE Exchange.
- Role: Trader
- Attributes: "EXCHANGE" , value : "NYSE"
- Attributes: "CURRENCY" , value : "USD"

### XACML Request Input 1

- Name: Jay
- Role: Trader
- Attribute: EXCHANGE:NYSE
- Attribute: CURRENCY:USD

### XACML Request Input 2

- Name: John
- Role: Trader
- Attribute: EXCHANGE:NYSE
- Attribute: CURRENCY:GBP

### XACML Request Input 3

- Name: Mat
- Role: Trader
- Attribute: EXCHANGE:NYSE

An attribute is a key/value pair.

### Expected output.

On evaluating the XACML policy for the above requests:

- Jay should get PERMIT and
- John should get "DENY".
- Mat should receive PERMIT with obligation of "CURRENCY" as USD.

Could someone please help me with this policy?

Here is the ALFA policy which will perform an RBAC check given below

```java
  namespace RBACPolicy {
    attribute activityRoles {
        id = "activity:role"
        type = string
        category = resourceCat
    }

    attribute userRoles {
        id = "subject:role"
        type = string
        category = subjectCat
    }

    policyset genericpolicy {
        apply denyOverrides

        policy genericpolicy_1 {
            apply denyOverrides

            rule rule1{
                permit
                    condition stringAtLeastOneMemberOf(activityRoles, userRoles)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks David for editing this request in proper format.
I would also like to add one more point to this question.
A user can have multiple combinations of attributes.
Say Jay can have trades on NYSE with USD and FTSE on GBP. So XACML policy has to evaluate the combination of attributes.

- User profile

  - Name: Jay
  - Role: Trader Attribute: EXCHANGE: NYSE Attribute: CURRENCY: USD
  - Role: Trader Attribute: EXCHANGE: FTSE Attribute: CURRENCY: INR

### Request

Can Jay View Trades on BSE with INR?

Comment: Do you expect a user to take only one role at a time like `Trader` in the XACML Request (regardless of EXCHANGE and CURRENCY)? Or could you have `Trader` and another role, e.g. `Manager`, both in the same XACML request? The possible solutions would be different in this case.